# Unable to dynamically load dropdown list using Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, illuminate-container

I'm new to Laravel and Blade and have been trying to create a view using `Illuminate/Html`.

I have a table called `service_locations(location_id, location_area)`.

Using the above table I'm trying to populate the below dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('location', 'Location:') !!}
{!! Form::select('location', array(

    @foreach($locations as $local)
       '{{ $local->location_id }}' => '{{ $local->location_area }}', 
    @endforeach

), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

But as I attempt to do so, I am getting the following error in the second-last line (`), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`):

```
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'
```

I am not able to figure out the issue with the above code.

**Edit 1**
Here's what my controller looks like:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\service_location;
use App\service_type;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $locations = service_location::all();
        $services = service_type::all();

        return view('home.index', compact('locations','services'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use blade structures (`@foreach`) to build a PHP array. You should definitely prepare that data in the controller and pass it to the view

Comment: @lukasgeiter Please recheck. I've updated the question to include my controller code here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use blade that way,

but you can achieve the same result with

```
{!! Form::select('location', $locations->lists('id','location_area'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}
```

Comment: I have already fetched all the necessary records in the table into the `$locations` object and passed them using the `compact()` function to the view. Also I have been following [this laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/9).

Comment: @ikartik90 This answer is totally correct. `lists()` is a method that you can call on collections. It will return an array that consists of a value (and optionally a key) from your model

Comment: Thanks for the answer Terry. It worked for me. But I'm still not clear on why my approach won't work when it works for Jeff in the laracast. And if I've understood it correctly, `lists` is a `value, key` pair and not a `key, value` pair, right?

Comment: How am I supposed to create a dropdown list like this: `echo Form::select('animal', array(
    'Cats' => array('leopard' => 'Leopard'),
    'Dogs' => array('spaniel' => 'Spaniel'),
));`

Comment: @ikartik90 you are already doing fine with the syntax above, the above multi-dimensional array will output dropdownlist with optgroup

or are you asking for how to organize your array to the format above ?

Comment: @terrylow I wish to organize the array in the above format.

Comment: with the model of this question ??

you might want to visit this page, this might come in handy with your case,
#http://laravel.io/forum/02-07-2014-macro-formselect-with-optgroups-based-on-models-field

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

In Controller:

```
$services = service_type::lists('location_area', 'location_id');

return view('home.index', compact('locations','services'));
```

In your blade:

```
 {{ Form::select('location',$locations,null, array('class'=> 'form-control'))}}
```

Comment: i have post my answer check it and let me know